# using where to filter total

Tags: sql

I need some help finding the error in this code.
Can I use where to filter the result?

```
SELECT OrderID, sum(UnitPrice * Quantity) as Total
FROM [Order Details]
WHERE Total > 10
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use the aggregate function SUM, you need to GROUP BY on the OrderId.

And you can then filter on the results of the aggregate functions in the HAVING clause.

Filtering on OrderId on the other hand would be done in the WHERE clause.

But depending on the type of database, using an alias name (f.e. Total) in the HAVING clause isn't allowed.

So in standard SQL it then would become something like this :

```
SELECT OrderID, SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity) as Total
FROM "Order Details"
GROUP BY OrderID
HAVING SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity) > 10
```